# Does CreateFromObservable works asynchrony?

Tags: reactiveui

I'm trying use ReactiveUI 7.4 in WPF project, and I think it's great framework. But it causes great difficulties in studying the absence, or the outdated documentation.
In doc https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/asynchronous-synchronous.html says so CreateFromObservable is asynchrony, but in my example it's run syncronly.

```
RefreshList = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable<ReactiveList<ClientDto>>(
                        () => Observable
                            .Return(_clientsService.GetClientsList())
```

and latter

```
   _isBusy = this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.RefreshList.IsExecuting)
            .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.IsBusy);
```

when i do InvokeCommand method runs syncronly, and IsExecuting observe only after GetClientsList() completed (change to false and after to true). But variand with task works:

```
RefreshList = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ =>
            {
                return await Task.Run(() => _clientsService.GetClientsList());
            }
        );
```

Is it bug? Or changes in framework? 
PS I also trying plays with SubscribeOn and ObservableOn but nothing helps (((.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.Return()` does it's work on the current thread, which means it's blocking. In your case the current thread is the UI thread.

You can specify a scheduler, but that only affects where the value is returned, not where it's produced.

I've written about `Observable.Return()` and how it behaves in [this blog post](https://blog.jonstodle.com/beware-observable-return-and-its-scheduler/).

It looks like `_clientsService.GetClientsList()` is implemented synchronously. To make it asynchronous you can move the work to the task pool. You've already done this by running it in a `Task`. It's also possible to use `Observable.Start()´:

```
RefreshList = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable<ReactiveList<ClientDto>>(
                        () => Observable
                            .Start(_clientsService.GetClientsList(), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler);
```